# Issue while converting java code to Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I am trying to convert below Java code into Kotlin.

I am getting two errors, I think due to constructors.

Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but AuthNM? was expected

**Java Code**

```
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import android.content.Context;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class AuthNM {

    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    public static AuthNM instance = null;

    private AuthNM(Context context) {
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public static AuthNM getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new AuthNM(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

**Kotlin Code**

```
class AuthNM {
    private var requestQueue: RequestQueue? = null
    var instance: AuthNM? = null

    private fun AuthNM(context: Context?) {
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext())
    }

    fun getInstance(context: Context): AuthNM? {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = AuthNM(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why has the constructor in the Java version become a method in the Kotlin version? Also, which IDE are you using? IntelliJ at least offers a Java to Kotlin conversion which "works" and then you can tidy up as required.

Comment: This was done by IntelliJ itself.

Comment: The Java version is already pretty puzzling, to be frank. It looks like a singleton pattern, but it's not really. The assignment of the static instance is not thread safe, and more importantly the instance is created with the `Context` of the first `getInstanc()` invocation, and then other contexts are ignored. This seems pretty wrong. Also, why is the static instance field public?

Comment: You can use the built in migration in Android Studio. What I did was right click the "app" then click convert, then I went into each Activity.kt and done the same. It converts 98% of the code, the other 2% is tidying up, like imports and stuff. The converter is not 100% accurate but it will get you in the 90% range and then you just adjust the remaining code.